# DataGridViewComboBoxCell datasource clears when sorting columns on datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have DataGridViewComboBoxCell in winforms application that I'm filling with some datasource for each row.
This is what I find on this thread [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn adding different items to each row .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91745/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-adding-different-items-to-each-row) 
And this is working fine, every row has different drop down values as supposed to be.
But when I click mouse on column header and sorting occurs, all DataGriViewComboBoxCells are cleared, and no value could be choosen. I must have sorting for columns. No exception occurs. Some solution?

```
    private void setCellComboBoxItems(DataGridView dataGrid, int rowIndex, int colIndex, object[] itemsToAdd)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcbc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dataGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex];
        // You might pass a boolean to determine whether to clear or not.
        dgvcbc.Items.Clear();
        foreach (object itemToAdd in itemsToAdd)
        {
            dgvcbc.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can try setting your `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`s again after sorting in dgv `Sorted` method?

Comment: Maybe, but those data is filled from database, it is very expensive if I have 100 rows and for each row 4-5 records. But if I do not find other solution, that is what I will do.

Comment: Can you cache the data and restore after the sort?

Comment: Well thanks that is what I'm doing now. Cache it into Datatable and then re-run filling them. If someone knows better solution I'm open for suggestions.