# C# DatagridviewComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

In a Winform application, how can I manage this case :
I have a datagridview, with 2 columns, each contains a datagridviewcombobox

In the first I would list the constructor of some vehicles (BMW, FORD, etc)
In the second I would like that the content of the combobox is refreshed depending what I selected in the first combo, for example to display the model of the car

Thank you for any help

Best Regards

Austin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn adding different items to each row .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91745/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-adding-different-items-to-each-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can Handle the event handle `SelectedIndexChanged` so whenever the index is changed refresh the data example :

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {

             your_refresh_method_here();//


        }
    }
```

**Please note that `e` is the item selected by the user**

For any additional data please refer to: 
[Event that fires during DataGridViewComboBoxColumn SelectedIndexChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141872/event-that-fires-during-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-selectedindexchanged)